# Color Shift after uploading image to Magento admin

Tags: admin, image

We have a client is complaining they are getting a color shift when uploading an image. If we don't have anything modifying images in the admin section, what could be affecting colors after image upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is they are using Mac/Firefox and have sRGB profiles embedded within their images.

Magento requires the `GD2` library be installed prior to installation. Most all "Image" facilities will get pushed through it for resizing, thumbnail generation, etc.

The alternative is ImageMagick as it tends to have better quality results, however processing time may be greatly increased.  Not to mention cranking up quality means slower download times on the client end as well.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773032/how-to-stop-gd2-from-washing-away-the-colors-upon-resizing-images

A drop-in replacement (ImageMagick adapter) for Magento:

- https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks

You can also try and increase the quality with `->setQuality(90)` in any calls to the images to see if it helps, but I'm going to assume the color profiles is the source of the issues, and possibly GD2's library.

A few questions: What file types are they using, and what color profiles if any? Also, a version of GD2 may help as well. You should be able to find this in `phpinfo();`

Hope this helps...

Some further reading:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6158/P135/#t299873
- http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=125838
- http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/sRGB-AdobeRGB1998.htm

Answer (score 1):

As B00MER identified, this is an issue with the GD2 library.  Thanks to the below links, I found another solution which doesn't require any Magento/library changes.

- This one explains the issue well:  http://www.human-element.com/a-tale-of-two-images/  On that page, follow the "easy" link to get a tool which will automatically update your images to resolve the issue.
- This one gives directions to resolve one image at time manually, and I used this to confirm the fix works:  http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-use-colorsync-utility-to-assign-color-profiles-in-os-x/

All of these are dependent on OSX, it might be more difficult to do without access to a mac.